# ¿Como crear UPDATE con php y sql?

Tags: php, sql

estoy teniendo un problema, intento hacer el update a mi bd pero aunque haga click y me aparezca sin errores sigue mostrando los mismos datos que tenia anteriormente. mi llave primaria es cedula y los otros campos son nombre, apellido, direccion, telefono. la tabla se llama administracion. como logro que el update cumpla la funcion y termine actualizando todos los datos que le ingreso en los campos de los formulario??.

cualquier consejo que me hagan aparte de la pregunta sera bienvenido. espero me puedan ayudar amigos, espero sus respuestas :)

```
<?php
    
        $servidor="localhost";
        $usuario="root";
        $password="17122001";
        $db="sistema";

        $conexion= new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$password,$db);

        if ($conexion->connect_error) {
            die("conexion fallida" . $conexion->connect_error);
        }
        
        $cedula=$_GET['cedula'];
    
        $sql="SELECT * FROM administracion where cedula = $cedula";
        $resultado=$conexion->query($sql);
            while($row= $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                $nombre = $row['nombre'];
                $apellido =  $row['apellido'];
                $direccion = $row['direccion'];
                $telefono = $row['telefono'];
    }
    
    

?>

<div class="formulario-registro">
        
        <form action="administracion.php" method="POST">
            
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type='text' name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre ?>" size="25" maxlength="20" minlength="3" required>

            <br />

            <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
            <input type='text' name="apellido" value="<?php echo $apellido ?>" size="25" maxlength="20" minlength="3" required >

            <br />

            <label for="cedula">Cedula</label>
            <input type='text' name="cedula" value="<?php echo $cedula ?>" size="25" maxlength="12" minlength="3" required>

            <br />

            <label for="direccion">Direccion</label>
            <input type='text' name="direccion" value="<?php echo $direccion ?>" size="25" maxlength="35" minlength="3" >

            <br />

            <label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
            <input type='text' name="telefono" value="<?php echo $telefono ?>" size="25" maxlength="12" minlength="3" >

            <br />
            <br />

            <label for="cargo">Cargo</label>
            <select name="cargo[]">
                  <option value="administracion"> Administracion </option>
                  <option value="docente"> Docente </option>
                  <option value="limpieza"> Limpieza </option>
                  <option value="vigilante"> Vigilante </option>
            </select>

            <br />

             <input class="boton-registro" type="submit" name="actualizar" placeholder="Actualizar" value="Actualizar" required>

        </form>
        </div>
        <?php
        $nombre2=$_POST["nombre"];
        $apellido2=$_POST["apellido"];
        $cedula2=$_POST["cedula"];
        $direccion2=$_POST["direccion"];
        $telefono2=$_POST["telefono"];
        

        if (isset($_POST['cedula'])){
                $sql="UPDATE administracion SET cedula=$cedula2, nombre='$nombre2', apellido='$apellido2', direccion='$direccion2', telefono='$telefono2' WHERE cedula = $cedula";
                if($conexion->query($sql) === true){
                }
                else{
                    die("ERROR: " . $conexion->error);
                }
        }
        
        $conexion->close();
?>
```

Comment: en el `where` y `set` te faltan las comillas de `$cedula`, debe ser string.

Comment: @Bicho no necesariamente..habria que ver como lo definio en la base de datos...

Comment: el error es que en el where estas pasando $cedula, pero en tu codigo defines $cedula2 como variable...

Comment: no es string, es int

Comment: @gbianchi pero si es para modificar la tabla original en el WHERE la cedula no debe ser la original antes de ser modificada? fijate que cedula es la original y cedula2 es la actualizada

Comment: Claro, pero si hay cédulas que empiece con `0` entonces no podrías utilizar `int` y depende del número de dígitos el `int` tiene limite de `bytes`.

Comment: Entonces cedula no deberia ser la clave de la tabla... deberias tener un id propio como clave si la cedula es modificable....

Comment: quite la opcion de modificar la cedula y aun no actualiza datos

Comment: Como bien dice @gbianchi (y creo que te lo comenté en otra pregunta), la llave primaria no debería ser editable, eso te puede crear un caos en la base de datos si dejas que el usuario modifique llaves primarias. Si la cédula puede editarse, entonces deberías cambiar la llave primaria por un `ID` autoincremental. Si dices que no te funciona al quitar la cédula del `SET`
, es porque en el `WHERE` no estás usando la variable correcta, prueba así: `$sql="UPDATE administracion SET nombre='$nombre2', apellido='$apellido2', direccion='$direccion2', telefono='$telefono2' WHERE cedula = $cedula2";`

Comment: va a sonar raro pero intenta hacer la actualización desde workbench o phpmyadmin y compárala con la consulta arrojada por php.  Así identificarás si es un problema con llaves o esas cosas.

Comment: @A.Cedano sigue teniendo el mismo problema. no actualiza

Comment: Prueba a imprimir la variable con algo como `echo $sql;` y dinos lo que muestra.

Answer (score 0):

$sql="SELECT * FROM administracion where cedula = $cedula";

Cuando ejecutas esa consulta no mandas el valor de $cedula debes ocupar comillas simples para concatenar variables, intenta con algo así:

$sql = "select * from administracion where ceduda = '$cedula'";

Saludos.

Comment: Lo mismo pasa cuando ejecutas el update:           $sql="UPDATE administracion SET cedula=$cedula2, nombre='$nombre2', apellido='$apellido2', direccion='$direccion2', telefono='$telefono2' WHERE cedula = $cedula";  el valor de "cedula 2" no está concatenado

Comment: El OP indico en los comentarios de la pregunta que `$celuda` es `int`, así que no serían necesarias las comillas simples. Saludos.